# Help center might need a few additions

Tags: discussion, help-center

Now that we're in public beta, it might be a good time to think about expanding parts of the help center. For example the [what's on topic](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page isn't as helpful to new users as it can be.

Additionally, the text [here](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask):

> (The above section was adapted from MetaFilter’s FAQ.)

that suggests that *at some point*, it should be edited.

So my question is how are pages in the help center made\edited?

#### Edit:

Well, we now have mods. And also building a [faq](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/203/what-does-a-new-member-need-to-know-on-this-site). The faq can theoretically point to the help center, but then the help center should be updated.

Comment: @TuringTux Agreed. As Aurora said in his answer, moderators can edit certain things in the tour. All these things would wait, I presume, until we have [Moderators Pro Tempore].(https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site).

Comment: @TuringTux I don't think it matters that much. But it might be useful for removing noise

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So my question is how are pages in the help center made/edited?

Moderators can edit:

- [What topics can I ask about here?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)
- The introductory text and checklists of the [tour](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/tour). (an example question can also be chosen from an eligible pool)

The rest of the help center, including [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask), are **not** editable by moderators. It may be possible to ask the Community Managers to change this if there is a **very compelling reason**, but I've other pages in the help center changed per-site.

On a slight tangential note, moderators can also add up to three custom 'off-topic' closure reasons. They're often used for particularly common questions that aren't on-topic for a site, such as Stack Overflow's:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

---

On to how the pages can be changed on this site:

1. Once the [Moderators Pro Tempore](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site) are selected, [a discussion](https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1252/4164) can be started on what to add to the help center. Typically, it helps to have some sort of draft/proposal to work from, rather than just a big thread asking for everything that could possibly be listed.
2. Once a consensus is reached, the pages can be edited as necessary. If it's not working out, the pages can always be revised by moderators—it's not a final document, set in stone forever!

Comment: Ok. Then we'll just have to wait until mods pro tempore are selected :)