# Site scope thoughts

Tags: discussion, site-scope

As we continue through our public beta phase, site definition remains rather important. The decisions made in the next few weeks will guide the site for a long time to come. They will also help us when it *is* time to [Make the help center more helpful](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/q/164/104).

As *Computer Science* educators there are many things to deal with, or *issues* as they are sometimes labeled. Some directly relate to the subject matter of computer science. Others relate to the way the classroom is managed. There are even issues that don't relate specifically to computer science or the classroom. Many of the problems encountered outside the scope of the subject matter itself are common to most educators, regardless of the subject matter, and may, or may not, be modified by the subjects taught.

As I perceive this site within the whole of the Stack Exchange network, it is *a* resource for Computer Science educators, but not *the* resource. It should not aim to be the *one true and correct* source for all things any CS instructor needs to know. Rather, it should fill in some of the gaps left by existing communities in the Stack Exchange network. Some of the communities that exist, which a CS instructor could use are: (If I missed a good one, let me know, or edit it in.)

- [Super User](https://superuser.com/)

  - Specific issues with computer software, hardware or networking (including the operating system when things don't work anymore)
- [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)

  - Specific programming problems
  - Software algorithms
  - Coding techniques
  - Software development tools
- [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) - Useful for theoretical questions about:

  - algorithms, models of computation
  - programming language semantics, formal methods
  - computer architecture, networks
  - machine learning, artificial intelligence, knowledge representation, natural language processing
  - vision, graphics
- [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) - Useful for *working* samples of program code that you plan to use for your class and want a review relative to:

  - Best practices and design pattern usage
  - Security issues
  - Performance
  - Correctness in unanticipated cases

When, however the issue deals with presenting the material to the students, that's where we **shine**. That's what makes this site a unique, and useful, part of the Stack Exchange network.

What none of those sites, and with the possible exceptions of [Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) and [Mathematics Educators](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/), none of the rest of the network sites address, are the issues outside our subject matter that instructors have to address. Things like:

- Classroom management
- Environment of the classroom
- Educational "Best Practices"
- Curriculum and lesson development
- Intra-institutional and interdepartmental relations
- Parent-teacher relations
- Student engagement
- and more that don't come to mind, but will be encountered eventually

In deciding what *is* "on-topic" for our site we will have to draw some lines that might be uncomfortable, as it could result in questions that have no home on the Stack Exchange network. As well, there will likely be issues that CS educators have to deal with that are just so far from our core as to be "off-topic," in spite of our personal wishes.

For questions that directly relate to the subject, Computer Science, the lines are not quite so hard to find. If it is about *teaching*, either presentation, explanation to the students, lesson ideas, etc., then it probably is on-topic. If it's about explaining to the instructor about what the theory is, or how something works, that's probably better on one of the sites above. A recent example of this is probably [How to teach random number generator algorithms?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/990/104)

Similarly, though a bit tougher, is whether or not the subject *is* computer science, or is it only computer *related*? Teaching number theory, while useful, if not important, in some cases, probably is *not* on-topic here. How to use a software, as a user, such as Office products and web browsers, or how to send email, draw graphics, and orgainize files, isn't computer science, it's computer literacy. What about mail-merge or macros in Word? I don't know. Maybe it comes down to how much it's "theory" and how much it's "usage". Do we draw the line that says Excel macros are *out*, VB scripts in Excel are *in*? Again, I don't know. I can speculate, however, that the father we drift from "computer science" toward "information technologies" and "computer literacy", the more diluted the site will become, and the less effective it will be for it's envisioned purpose.

For questions that relate to conducting the class, things get a lot murkier. Classroom management, something every instructor has to address on a daily basis, is a solid gray zone of complications. How to deal with out-of-norm students can depend on why, and how, they are out-of-norm. The misbehaving student is a discipline issue, and not for here. The over/under achiever might be for here. The overachiever, if challenged with advance material might become a class asset, or he might become a discipline problem all his own. Some questions that fall in this group are:

- Classroom Management, heavily CS related

  - [Video Games during class](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/335/104)
  - [Thoughts on copying and pasting code?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/706/104)
  - [How to handle students who excel at coding but aren't interested in theory](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/1037/104)
- Classroom Management, not specifically CS related

  - [Do your students pay attention when you speak?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/761/104)
  - [How to deal with very low performing students?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/927/104)

How to explain to the Dean what it is that you really teach seems on-topic, while explaining why you need to upgrade the classroom's computers, or raise the budget, seems off-topic. How to integrate GitHub into student projects, or use it for lesson plans and project materials seems good. How to set up a GitHub repository, how to do push, pull, commit, etc. on GitHub doesn't seem like it's appropriate for here.

To tie it all together, and cut it into pieces, I think part of what I see happening is that things are being accepted, or rejected, based on personal responses similar to "I would like to know that too," and "we don't do that here," or "that's the way everyone else in my district does it." There are going to be some things that our users have to do, that just are *not* related to the site. The middle school instructor that has to be "hall monitor" for 1 period each day is still a CS educator, but how to deal with the school bully just isn't a question that fits here. Same thing applies to budget requests, writing quarterly reviews, and who knows what else some of us have to endure, just to have the *privilege* of teaching computer science to students that may not listen.

In between the subject matter we teach and the management of the classrooms lies a range of potential topics (with current sample questions):

- Environment

  - [What is the best layout for a Middle School computer lab?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/787/104)
  - [How can I set up Eclipse/eGit/GitHub in a way that is easy for students?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/628/104)
  - [In-class server access limits](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/375/104)
- Tools and software

  - [Do you use any teaching assistant tool in your CS1 lab classes?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/905/104)
  - [Should CS students be doing their tests on paper?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/628/104)
- Educational issues

  - [Do you see the “Bimodal Distribution” too?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/756/104)
  - [How is your teaching affected by how you learned?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/754/104)
  - [Can sharing learning stats be beneficial to guide beginner students?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/992/104)
- Methods and objectives, possibly indirect relation to CS

  - [Homework Policy for Advanced/Honors Students](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/498/104)
  - [Instructional Methods for In-class Code Demos](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/415/104)
  - [What to say about the ethics of hacking](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/1079/104)
- Institutional and Extra-curricular issues

  - [Opportunities for Interdepartmental Collaboration](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/682/104)
  - [How can I explain the difference between CS and coding to a layperson?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/918/104)
  - [How to explain what code is to my parents?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/868/104)
  - [Overcoming a friend's self-discouragement](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/948/104)

Lastly, to travel full circle, I'll return to the subject matter. Deciding what subjects to consider as "Computer Science" for this site does not need to be tied to any other organisation, or other Stack Exchange site. If [Computer Science Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) chooses to accept as on-topic something that we do not, or they reject something as off-topic that we want to consider on-topic, that is acceptable. This is *our* site, not an annex of that site. Similarly, merely because the CS department, or the one CS instructor, of a school, or district teaches a given subject does not make it a CS subject. For years reproductive education was taught by the athletics department, yet *most* people would not classify that as an athletics, or sports, subject. In that line, an example of a recent question that "sounds" like it fits, but does not, is [While giving an introduction to the Internet, should I talk about the risks?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/1023/104).

For most of the examples given, I am not saying they are good or bad, high-quality or low-quality, or even "on-topic" or "off-topic". I merely use them as examples of current questions that apply to a certain category, and that can be used to discuss what, or how much, is going to be considered on-topic as we move forward.

Comment: Thank you very much for this detailed post and the effort you've made to write this (usually I'd just +1, but in this case I thought I had to say something special ;)). This will surely come in handy in further site scope discussions.

Comment: In the area of computer science vs computer related, one specific subarea is teaching computer programming. My first reaction to a lot of the questions on main is "That's not CS". Perhaps the most extreme example I've seen so far is [Should teachers enforce standardization of spacing and braces?](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/q/1456/1219).

Comment: What about adding to the list of related sites [Interpersonal Skills](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/). From their tour page "...is a question and answer site for people looking to improve their interpersonal communication skills". Disclaimer I'm not an active member of that site yet but I will be exploring it in the next days with an "online mentor" mindset. They have the tag [`teachers`](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/teachers)