# Let's name our main room!

Tags: discussion, status-completed, chat

When our site was created, we were given a [main chat room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174). Just like all the other sites, we were given the default name, which is the same name as our site name: "Computer Science Educators".

On many other sites, they get creative and think up a better name for their room, and we should do the same. Do you have any good ideas for room names? Suggest them here! The best one, as determined by voting, will be chosen when the activity on this question quiets down.

This was already discussed and a few suggested accumulated [in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174/conversation/room-naming).

Comment: Will giving it a different name make it harder for those not in the know to find?

Comment: @EllenSpertus [All the CS Educators rooms are associated together in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=cseducators.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I'm trying to think of a nerdy name, like the (not very good) hockey team I was on, The Halting Problem. The better team was Execution Time.

Answer (score 4):

"The Classroom" would fit well with "The Guidance Office" for the question help room.

Comment: maybe "the class room", so that it ends with *room*.

Comment: @ItamarGreen Why does it have to end with room?

Comment: @thesecretmaster It doesn't but I think it's nicer if it does.

Answer (score 1):

"The Quad"

The quad is defined as:

> a quadrangle, as on a college campus.

<sup>[Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/quad)</sup>

It is typically a central location where people go to hang out or and/or discuss important issues. Events are held on the quad, and it's generally a central multi-purpose area.

Comment: I'm with `The Quad` for the main room. IIRC faculty and student body both used the quad as an area to meet, and freely associate without the strictures of lecture hall or office. Relative to the main site, the chat room seems to fill that same purpose. I also like `Guidance Office` for the room to offer help in getting questions to meet the guidelines for posting.

Answer (score 1):

Second suggestions: The drawing board.

It's nice because when something we discuss there doesn't work, we say "back to the drawing board". And the chat is where we *sketch* ideas (that sometimes become [meta essays](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/172/site-scope-thoughts) or [well-organized collaborations](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142/introducing-the-introductory-programming-tag-cleanup)).

So we *draw* outlines on *the drawing board* and later discuss them in meta.

Answer (score 1):

When comments start to get a bit off topic, it might be a good idea to continue the discussion in ***Office Hours***.

Answer (score 0):

Morning Java.

Java -> reference to the language and coffee, which everyone knows all adults (including teachers) run on. Inspired by this comic:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> The Central Teaching Unit

It's a joke based off the Central Processing Unit.

Answer (score 0):

> The Binary Room

Because the teachers are zero and the students are one. Or you can have it the other way around.

Note: I am **not** trying to offend anybody in anyway at all.

Answer (score 0):

I propose "Hello, World!" as it references the [basic first program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Hello,_World!%22_program) of many students and it sounds welcoming.