# Please welcome your pro tem moderators!

Tags: discussion, moderation

First off, thanks to everyone who participated at the [unofficial moderator nominations](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75/accepting-nominations-who-should-moderate-this-site) meta post!

Throughout the beta, we need members from this site whose focus is to engage the community, both in community-building issues and site management. That's why we select a few members from each community to act as temporary, provisional Moderators. You can read about the program here: [**Moderator Pro Tempore**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/07/27/moderator-pro-tempore/) (complete with super retro screenshots!).

I am pleased to announce that these members have stepped up and generously volunteered their time to help us ensure that this community’s issues are properly addressed:

[image: Ben I.]
[image: thesecretmaster]
[image: Peter]

I may eventually be contacting additional users to fill more moderator slots, but I wanted to get initial mods activated before we got too far into the public beta.

We want to make this site a huge success, and these members are great examples of exactly the type of people we need to make this site succeed. Please welcome them for the hard work and time they contribute.

#### Did I overlook anyone?

Yes, almost certainly. At the nomination post alone, there were more great choices than positions available. There are members who are actively involved and very deserving of recognition. My inability to account for everyone this early on is in *no way* a slight against them. Ideally, Moderators are elected by the community and that's why **you'll have your elections several weeks after graduation.**

Most of all, be respectful and understanding of the Moderators Pro Tem. Members of your community are volunteering their time and learning on the job. It’s a learning experience for everyone.

Comment: Congrats to all of you!

Comment: If you want to talk to any of us you can [ping us in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59174). If you believe that we've made mistakes or done anything questionable, feel free to create a meta question about it or come to us personally in chat or do both.

Comment: @thesecretmaster now you think it will be good. But later, once the site is large enough, you can't handle all the pings and meta questions. So, if someone think you made any mistake, ask them to flag the post for mod's attn.

Comment: @SagarV If a user would like to notify us of another users behavior, then they should use flagging. If they just want to talk to us, chat is fine, and if they want to criticize/question/judge us meta or chat or both is fine.

Comment: _if they want to criticize/question/judge us_ hope you won't make such a scenario. All the best.

Answer (score 4):

### A hearty welcome and congratulations to our new moderators.

May they still enjoy the site as much as before.

If things get too far out of hand, you can always put out a few fires with this.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's only the first step not the last.

The party is going to start.

As the community grows, the flags, comments, rude and offences, Lol!!

Moderation of stack exchange sites are not easy as teaching. But people with experience in teaching can do far better.

#### Let's welcome our pro-tem mod's together.

This may help you to dig problems
[image]

Answer (score 1):

**Congratulations to all of you!**

I am sure that you will do a great job to support the community with your newly gained moderator powers and want to thank you all for the time you have already spent and will spend to build and manage this community.

`:)`